# Javascript onClick ShowHide controlling my entire header

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, hide, show

i have a javascript code that shows an input onClick. the problem is, it is controlling my entire header : if you click the logo, the ad, anything around; the input shows below.
is there an option to set the width or do something to prevent my code from controlling the entire header?
HTML :

```
<div id="element2" onClick="javascript:changeText(2);showhide('search-form-ft');ftinPut();" class="element2">search</div>
<div class="cse-branding-right" id="search-form-ft" style="display:none;">
  <div class="cse-branding-form">
    <form class="search-form" action="http://www.google.com" id="cse-search-box-ft" target="_blank">
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-5818823801401028:2026832598" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
        <input  id="ftinPut" class="ftinPut" type="text" name="q" size="24" placeholder="what would you like to search?" />
        <input type="image" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/orange-ico.png" class="orange-ico" title="well, search it!" />
<font title="Powered by Google Custom Search" class="poweredcse">Powered by <img class="watermark" title="Google ">custom search</font>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js :

```
function changeText(idElement) {
    var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
    if (idElement === 2) {
        if (element.innerHTML === 'search') element.innerHTML = 'cancel';
        else {
            element.innerHTML = 'search';
        }
    }
}
function ftinPut() {
    document.getElementById("ftinPut").select();
}
var state = 'none';
function showhide(layer_ref) {
if (state == 'block') { 
state = 'none'; 
} 
else { 
state = 'block'; 
} 
if (document.all) { //IS IE 4 or 5 (or 6 beta) 
eval( "document.all." + layer_ref + ".style.display = state"); 
} 
if (document.layers) { //IS NETSCAPE 4 or below 
document.layers[layer_ref].display = state; 
} 
if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) { 
hza = document.getElementById(layer_ref); 
hza.style.display = state; 
} 
}
```

& CSS :

```
.element2 {
  padding-left:22px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:orange;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(230, 227, 202, 1);
  font-family:segoe UI light,candara,georgia;
  background:url(/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/search.png) left no-repeat;
  background-position:0 96px;
  background-size:21px;
}
.element2:hover {
  opacity:.7;
}
.ftinPut {
  height:28px;
  padding-left:28px!important;
  color:orange!important;
  border:none!important;
  font-family:segoe UI Light,candara;
  background:url(/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Pencil.png)left no-repeat;
  background-size:20px 20px;
  background-position:4px 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only to change the CSSs applied to that element.

Add this CSS rules to `element2` ant it will work fine:

```css
#element2 {
    margin-left: 192px;
    padding: 0; // or just remove the padding-left rule
    width: 72px;
}
```